# JRuby Net::HTTP Fails with OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: Certificates does not conform to algorithm constraints

Tags: java, https, jruby

Jruby jruby-1.7.0.preview1
JDK: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b05)

I'm getting data from a REST webservice over HTTPS, and for days now it's been fine.

I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 (from 11.10) over the weekend - and now this fails. I can only assume that something changed in my JVM during that time. I had thought I was on Java 7 before, so I'm very confused.

Either way the code that is fails on is the **Net::HTTP.start** part of:

```
require "net/http"

Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, :use_ssl => true, :ca_path => "/etc/ssl/certs") do |http|
  #...
end
```

And the error is:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: Certificates does not conform to algorithm constraints
    from org/jruby/ext/openssl/SSLSocket.java:180:in `connect'
    from /opt/jruby/active/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:799:in `connect'
    from org/jruby/ext/timeout/Timeout.java:103:in `timeout'
    from /opt/jruby/active/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:799:in `connect'
    from /opt/jruby/active/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
    from /opt/jruby/active/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:744:in `start'
    from /opt/jruby/active/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:557:in `start'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I just tested this on Java 6, and it worked fine.

I'm wondering if it has to do with: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2405379

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution outlined here:
http://sim.ivi.co/2011/07/java-se-7-release-security-enhancements.html

Short version:
Go into java_home/jre/lib/security/java.security
And change

```
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2
```

to

```
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=
```

However, please be aware that this re-enables MD2 hashing, which has proven to not be secure.

See:
https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2009-2409